# Can c# object change class dynamically?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a class from which two other classes inherit properties. Computer.cs properties are inherited by Desktop.cs and Laptop.cs. If I assign the Desktop class to an object, then need it to change to an object of the Laptop class, can I simply change the class? Or do I need to include constructors in each subclass that know how to create an object in the new class from the original class?

Example:
In a form, a user selects Desktop and begins filling in information for properties that comes from both the Computer class and Desktop class. Then, that user realizes that they meant to select Laptop. (Not sure how someone would make that mistake, so it's a silly example, I guess.) The user changes their selection to Laptop in a dropdown. Can C# handle dropping the uninherited properties from the object and adding the properties from the new class?

```
public class Computer 
{
  public string serial {get; set;} //serial number of PC
}

public class Laptop : Computer
{
  public bool bitlocker {get; set;} //was the laptop bitlockered?
}

public class Desktop : Computer
{
  public bool videoCard {get; set;} //was a video card installed?
}

//just a guess at what it would look like to change pc from Desktop to Laptop class using typecasting
Desktop pc = new Desktop();
Laptop pc = (Laptop)pc;
WriteLine(pc.serial); //returns the serial number set earlier
WriteLine(pc.videoCard); //error: property does not exist
WriteLine(pc.bitlocker); //returns false
```

After writing all of this, SO *suddenly* noticed a similar question from back in 2010. ([How to change the class of an object dynamically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498531/how-to-change-the-class-of-an-object-dynamically-in-c)) I suspect that there may have been changes in 5 years, so I'm going to go ahead an ask anyway.

Comment: You don't want `Laptop pc = (Laptop)pc;` to work. Luckily it will throw.

Comment: C# didn't change that much and it never will do this. As 1 of the answers on the dupe says "you have some design problems".

Comment: @HenkHolterman OK, further research shows that I have to create an explicit type conversion to handle what I want to do. I think it odd that c# wouldn't have this built-in.

Comment: _I think it odd that ..._ - that is very much on purpose. Which means you should carefully reconsider your solution. In what kind of domain model can Desktops turn into Laptops?

Comment: This is part of the back end for an ASP form. A tech has a configuration checklist for PCs that are imaged prior to sending them out to a user. If the tech gets in a hurry and selects Desktop, I don't want him to have to start over with a new checklist. It causes the tech frustration and could clog up the database with mistakes that someone has to clear out later.

Comment: That almost sounds like such a domain. But a checklist is about a computer, not part of it. A conversion of 1 type of checklist to another sounds plausible, but is about rearranging check items. Still not about changing types.